# Problem with multiple tags in URL

Tags: permalinks, tags

I used the link mydomain.com/tags/tag1,tag2/ on my Wordpress website with no problems whatsoever. But it doesn’t work from a certain moment. It displays error 403: Forbidden. I noticed that links with only tag works fine, but with multiple don’t. What could be a problem?

Comment: Did you changed a .htaccess file recently?

Comment: How was this set up? I don't remember if comma-separated supposed to just work, tagS is definitely not-default tag base.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you meant. I read about comma-separated tags in URL here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters 
I use one of the pre-prepared types the permalinks in the Preferences: mydomain.com/sample-post